# Auto expand regions in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, regions

<= Visual Studio 2012, you could use the *I Hate #Regions* plugin to auto expand regions, but this isn't available for 2013.

Is there an alternative, or is this option available natively now?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now Visual Studio 2013 support according to the site

[I Hate #Regions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ca60d35-1e02-43b7-bf59-ac7deb9afbca)

And OP has confirmed that it is working in VS2013 now. So we never have to be bothered by pesky regions again.

Comment: I tried it and it works. Could have checked my self though :) Add the fact that it works to your post please.

Comment: Yeah this came out after I asked the question, handy tool

Answer (score 0):

Slightly offtopic, but for the record:

[There are key combos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130722) for expanding and collapsing regions. The mentioned plugin just expands everything when a file is opened.